# Select hold values for inputs for live change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select id="pageSelect">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="pageInput" /> 
<textarea id="pageTextarea"></textarea>
```

And, after some research on Google and SO, I managed to make the following script:

```
$('#pageSelect').change(function(){
  $('#pageInput').val($(this).val());
  $('#pageTextarea').val($(this).val());
});
```

What this little script does, is to change the value of the input with the id `#pageInput` and the textarea with the id `#pageTextarea` to the value of the selected option from the `#pageSelect` select.

Then I added two more attributes to the `option` tag, `data-pagedescription` and `data-pagetitle`.

The goal is to get `#pageInput` to display `data-pagetitle` and `#pageTextarea` to display `data-pagedescription`.

How can I achieve this?

Here's a JS Fiddle with my progress so far: http://jsfiddle.net/9wb75038/15/ (updated to include jQuery)

Comment: Rather than posting an old example of markup and linking to the **actual** markup you have a problem with, put the actual markup in your question please.

Comment: Also the fiddle has no jQuery

Comment: Thanks! I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal is to get #pageInput to display data-pagetitle and #pageTextarea to display data-pagedescription.

You need to find the selected option element, then use jQuery's inbuilt [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function to get the relevant value.

```js
$('#pageSelect').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('#pageInput').val(selectedOption.data("pagetitle"));
    $('#pageTextarea').val(selectedOption.data("pagedescription"));
});
```

```css
select, input, textarea
{
    display:block;  
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="pageSelect">
    <option value="1" data-pagedescription="test description 1" data-pagetitle="test title 1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-pagedescription="test description 2" data-pagetitle="test title 2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3" data-pagedescription="test description 3" data-pagetitle="test title 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<!-- pageInput should get its data from data-pagetitle -->
<input type="text" id="pageInput" /> 

<!-- pageTextarea should get its data from data-pagedescription -->
<textarea id="pageTextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's working in the fiddle but it's not working on a blank html file on my server? Here is the link: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/admin/test.html. Thank you!

Comment: Two things wrong: 1) You need to close the `<script>` tag immediately after adding the jQuery script. Then open a new `<script>` tag for your JavaScript code afterwards. 2) All jQuery code must be executed from inside jQuery's document ready function. Replace the code in your page's `<head>` with the code from this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65782yev/2/ ... jQuery document ready document: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1):

Another way for you to understand better is by declaring values end then use the val() function to write the value.

```
$('#pageSelect').change(function(){
   var opt = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-pagedescription'); // get the option value from attribute
   var opt2 = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-pagetitle');
   $('#pageInput').val(opt);
   $('#pageTextarea').val(opt2);
});
```

The result is the same as you expect. Hope it helps.